# App initialization is not allowed on emulators

Tags: android

i'm using Nexus 5 Android emulator version 7.0 which include play store i installed some apps which is working perfect but there's an app i need to work on it using UI Automator it's called Careem when i go to install from play store it says "your device isn't compatible with this version" however i download it from google chrome and i installed when i try to run app it say "App initialization is not allowed on emulators" is there any way to run it on emulator because i got no android device?

[Screen shot from emulator about msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzfRK.png)

Answer (score 0):

you emulator has x86 ABI.

chrome and Careem not support x86 ABI.

create device armeabli or armeabli-v7a.

[image]

Comment: i try that still same msg "App initialization is not allowed on emulators"